# How to split an array into a number of arrays based on increasing value by a given number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, reduce

I've written the following function:

```
const trends = hits.reduce((arr, curr, index, array) => {
      if (arr.includes(curr)) return arr
      if (curr + 1 === array[index + 1]) arr.push(curr, array[index + 1]);
      return arr;
    }, []);
```

The point is so that if an array contains a sequence of numbers which increase by 1 then this returns a new array with these values.
For instance: `[1, 2, 3, 6, 10]` would return `[1, 2, 3]`.

The problem is: if there's more than one sequence, I'd like to have it in a separate array (or in an array of subarrays). At this point, the function does the following `[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]`. I also can't predict how many trends there might be. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward approach, based on two conditions whose precedence can not be changed/swapped, which actually also reads what it does ...

```js
function collectItemSequences(list, item, idx, arr) {
  if ((item - 1) === arr[idx - 1]) {
    // in case of a predecessor ...

    // ... push item into the most recent sequence list.
    list[list.length - 1].push(item);

  } else if ((item + 1) === arr[idx + 1]) {
    // else, in case of a successor ...

    // ... create a new sequence list with its 1st item.
    list.push([ item ]);
  }
  return list;
}

console.log(
  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14].reduce(collectItemSequences, [])
);
console.log(
  [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14].reduce(collectItemSequences, [])
);
console.log(
  [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15].reduce(collectItemSequences, [])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Based on the above approach one could implement a more generic one which allows the configuration of how to compute a current item's *sequence predecessor* respectively *sequence successor* ...

```js
function collectItemSequencesByConditions(collector, item, idx, arr) {
  const { getPredecessor, getSuccessor, list } = collector;
  if (getPredecessor(item) === arr[idx - 1]) {

    // push item into the most recent sequence list.
    list[list.length - 1].push(item);

  } else if (getSuccessor(item) === arr[idx + 1]) {

    // create a new sequence list with its 1st item.
    list.push([ item ]);
  }
  return collector;
}

const conditions = {
  getPredecessor: currentItem => currentItem - 2,
  getSuccessor: currentItem => currentItem + 2,
};

console.log(
  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14].reduce(
    collectItemSequencesByConditions,
    { ...conditions, list: [] },
  ).list
);
console.log(
  [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14].reduce(
    collectItemSequencesByConditions,
    { ...conditions, list: [] },
  ).list
);
console.log(
  [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15].reduce(
    collectItemSequencesByConditions,
    { ...conditions, list: [] },
  ).list
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

The OP's Q

> I set up two pair of conditions, one for item `- 1`, item `+ 1`, second pair respectively for `- 10`, `+ 10`. The hits array was `[22, 31, 32, 33, 42, 52]`. I turned your `console.logs` into `const variable = hits.reduce...` so on. Then I returned both variables. The results were `[31, 32, 33]` and `[42, 52]`. The expected outcome for second is of course `[22, 33, 42, 52]`.

Firstly the OP most probably meant `[22, 32, 42, 52]`.

Secondly ...

Nope, math is reliable. And the algorithm can't be tricked. The rules which are applied for valid predecessors/successors are merciless. Thus the *"expected outcome for"* `[22, 31, 32, 33, 42, 52]` and `+/- 10` of cause is `[42, 52]` and not `[22, 32, 42, 52]`.

***Why?..*** The second value of `[22, 31, 32, 33, 42, 52]` is `31` which breaks any possible sequence (the OP expected `22`, `32`). Thus it is not a valid predecessor/successor sequence.

Here are some test cases ...

```js
console.log(
  "for [22, 31, 32, 33, 42, 52] and [-1 , +1]",
  "\nexpect: '[[31,32,33]]' ?",
  JSON.stringify([22, 31, 32, 33, 42, 52].reduce(
    collectItemSequencesByConditions, {
      getPredecessor: currentItem => currentItem - 1,
      getSuccessor: currentItem => currentItem + 1,
      list: [],
    }
  ).list) === '[[31,32,33]]'
);
console.log(
  [22, 31, 32, 33, 42, 52].reduce(
    collectItemSequencesByConditions, {
      getPredecessor: currentItem => currentItem - 1,
      getSuccessor: currentItem => currentItem + 1,
      list: [],
    }
  ).list
);

console.log(
  "for [22, 31, 32, 33, 42, 52] and [-10 , +10]",
  "\nexpect: '[[42,52]]' ?",
  JSON.stringify([22, 31, 32, 33, 42, 52].reduce(
    collectItemSequencesByConditions, {
      getPredecessor: currentItem => currentItem - 10,
      getSuccessor: currentItem => currentItem + 10,
      list: [],
    }
  ).list) === '[[42,52]]'
);
console.log(
  [22, 31, 32, 33, 42, 52].reduce(
    collectItemSequencesByConditions, {
      getPredecessor: currentItem => currentItem - 10,
      getSuccessor: currentItem => currentItem + 10,
      list: [],
    }
  ).list
);

console.log(
  "for [21, 22, 32, 33, 42, 52] and [-10 , +10]",
  "\nexpect: '[[22,32],[42,52]]' ?",
  JSON.stringify([21, 22, 32, 33, 42, 52].reduce(
    collectItemSequencesByConditions, {
      getPredecessor: currentItem => currentItem - 10,
      getSuccessor: currentItem => currentItem + 10,
      list: [],
    }
  ).list) === '[[22,32],[42,52]]'
);
console.log(
  [21, 22, 32, 33, 42, 52].reduce(
    collectItemSequencesByConditions, {
      getPredecessor: currentItem => currentItem - 10,
      getSuccessor: currentItem => currentItem + 10,
      list: [],
    }
  ).list
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  function collectItemSequencesByConditions(collector, item, idx, arr) {
    const { getPredecessor, getSuccessor, list } = collector;
    if (getPredecessor(item) === arr[idx - 1]) {

      // push item into the most recent sequence list.
      list[list.length - 1].push(item);

    } else if (getSuccessor(item) === arr[idx + 1]) {

      // create a new sequence list with its 1st item.
      list.push([ item ]);
    }
    return collector;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I've adopted your solution to my program. It works like a charm, thank you. One thing which is not very readable to me is the use of destructuring. I'm a beginner and I've never seen anyone use the accumulator in form of an object in reduce. Could you suggest any reading for me to understand this more clearly?

Comment: @esiale ... 1/2 ... I assume, you refer to the generic 2nd approach. Use it only if there are actually use cases for it. Otherwise stich to the 1st one. As for the accumulator and the destructuring ... well, the accumulator/collector can be anything one wants, for summing up number values it will be a finite number value, for concatenating strings it will be a string value, likewise for the target formats of arrays and objects. And of cause there ist no rule that does not allow the usage of accumulator/collector objects as `config` like objects for more generic, customizable use cases.

Comment: @esiale ... 2/2 ... One just needs to write the code readable enough and comment on the configuration in order to make clear what are the customizable parts and which property / key of the `config` / collector / accumulator is the actual result.

Comment: you're a daisy. Interestingly enough, I've ran into some issues with your second approach. (sadly I can't paste code here) I wrapped the whole method into a function which takes a single argument of hits. I set up two pair of conditions, one for item - 1, item + 2, second pair respectively for - 10, + 10. The hits array was `[22, 31, 32, 33, 42, 52]`. I turned your console.logs into const variable = hits.reduce... so on. Then I returned both variables. The results were [31, 32, 33] and [42, 52]. The expected outcome for second is of course [22, 33, 42, 52]. Something odd has occurred

Comment: I can't edit, this was a typo, I meant - 1, + 1

Comment: @esiale ... hopefully the above edit can explain why the algorithm is more correct than your expectation(s).

Answer (score 1):

You could let the accumulator be a combination of the partial result array, and the previous value (for easier access to it). To keep the code simple, you could add every current value, either to the last subarray, or as its own subarray. After `reduce` finishes, you can kick out those subarrays that only have one value:

```js
let hits = [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14];

const trends = hits.reduce(([arr, prev], curr, index, array) => {
    if (prev + 1 == curr) arr[arr.length-1].push(curr);
    else arr.push([curr]);
    return [arr, curr];
}, [[], NaN])[0].filter(row => row.length > 1);
    
console.log(trends);
```